# Ubuntu graphics Jitter

Tags: 20.04

I am quite new to Ubuntu and Linux systems in general. And lately, I have been noticing a noticeable lag on anything graphics related, from viewing video files to moving around windows. I have tried a few things like turning off sync to VBlank and Framebuffer object. But the issue persists.

Graphics:

Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
driver: amdgpu v: 5.6.0.20.20
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: amdgpu
resolution: 1920x1080~75Hz
OpenGL: renderer: Radeon RX 570 Series
v: 4.6.14736 Core Profile Context 20.20

VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]                      Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev ef)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480  /570/570X/580/580X/590]
Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
Kernel modules: amdgpu

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-Bit

Comment: What do you mean by "jitter"? Screen tearing? Specify graphics and drivers with the output of `inxi -G` or `sudo lshw -c display`. Update your question (use "edit") to include the output of either of these commands)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced what I can only describe as jittering when I had my screen refresh rate too low. If you open "displays" in settings, make sure your monitor refresh rate is somewhere like 60Hz. Mine was set to 25 initially.